# Problem with Titlesec / easy mode

Tags: titlesec

I want to change some fontsizes of headings and subheadings and tried this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\title}{\LARGE\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}
```

Now I always get the message `titlesec not allowed in easy mode`. Is there an alternative solution/how I can fix this?

Comment: Possibly a `duplicate`. See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134031/how-to-adjust-the-size-and-placement-of-chapter-heading-in-report-class

Answer (score 1):

`\title` is no sectioning command, so `titlesec` does nothing but to throw an error. (Admittedly the error and help messages are not particularly clear.) If you want to change the appearance of the title you should write the title page yourself or possibly patch `\maketitle` like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\@title}{\bfseries\@title}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries}

\title{My Great Masterpiece}
\author{Me Myself}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Bar}
\subsection{Baz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

By default the title is already `\LARGE` so there is no need to add it extra. Note also that your current use of `\titleformat*` corresponds to the standard definitions, so those lines aren't really doing anything useful.

Comment: There's also the  `titling`package, which defines useful commands to customise `\maketitle`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks. I must admit that I am not familiar with these packages: if I have to do something in a specific way I just hack the code myself `:-)`